# How to find empty rows from excel sheet given by user and delete them in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-core, epplus

```
public async Task<List<IndiaCIT>> Import(IFormFile file)
        {
            var list = new List<IndiaCIT>();
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

                using (var package=new ExcelPackage(stream))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                    var rowcount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
                   
                   
                    for (int row = 1; row <= rowcount; row++)
                    {
                       
                        list.Add(new IndiaCIT {

                            NameCH = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                            City= worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                            Age = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                            
                        });
                       
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

this is controller code and in model class  declared the columns name and used it as IndiaCIT list in controller,. I want empty rows to get deleted

Comment: You're using EPPlus, not just ASP.NET. The code you posted *reads* an uploaded Excel file, it doesn't manipulate or delete anything. What's your *real* question? How to skip empty rows?

Comment: Or is the real question how to use LINQ to read from that sheet?

Answer (score 1):

This could help:
For each row in the sheet, check if the cell in each column is empty. If so delete it.

```
var rowcount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
var maxColums = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

for(int row = rowcount; row > 0; row--)
{
    bool isRowEmpty = true;
    for(int column = 1; column <= maxColumns; column++)
    {
        var cellEntry = worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value.ToString();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellEntry)
        {
             isRowEmpty = false;
             break;
        }
     }
     if(!isRowEmpty)
        continue;
     else
        worksheet.DeleteRow(row);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I generally use `Spire.Xls` to handle such problems. It works for me.

```
    public IActionResult Test() {

        //init workbook
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        // load file
        workbook.LoadFromFile("11.xlsx");

        // get the first sheet
        Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

        //delete blank row 
        for (int i = sheet.Rows.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (sheet.Rows[i].IsBlank)
            {
                sheet.DeleteRow(i + 1); 
            }
        }
        //delete blank column
        for (int j = sheet.Columns.Count() - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (sheet.Columns[j].IsBlank)
            {
                sheet.DeleteColumn(j + 1); 
            }
        }

        //save as a new xls file
        workbook.SaveToFile("new.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2016);
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: This isn't helpful. The OP is using EPPlus. Telling them to switch to a commercial library without justification or explanation doesn't help

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When op get back and tell us details, I will update my answer.